# where icmp.c checks expires

Tags: c, networking, kernel, icmp

In `kernel-3.0.26 code net/ipv6/icmp.c`, while sending ICMP reply where it checks for the timer expiry. It should check the value give by a router advertisement right? I think the expiry value is stored in `rt->rt6_expires` in `ndisc.c` (line no: 1284). Then while sending an ICMP reply, it should check with the expiry timer right? Where that checking is done? Please somebody explain me.

Thank you in advance. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried the Linux Kernel mailing lists?

Comment: I didn't. I am afraid that lkml is a very big group and there are very great people are there. They may feel I am annoying them.

Comment: Consider asking on netdev mailing list. The great people there might be annoyed enough to answer.